# Unsure how to set uniform value to a vector

Tags: java, vector

So i have a problem where i have a vector class, and if the user wants to set a uniform value to the int they type in. This is my code so far:

```
public static Vector uniform(int length, long value) {

    /*
        EXAMPLE
        length 4, value 4 => [4 4 4 4]
    */

    Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    //for loop to iterate through each elements & set value?

    return new Vector(length);
}
```

The part with the reminder was the part i was unsure about. When the vector main program is run and the user types in "Set a = uniform 4", then the number 4 must become the value for all the numbers in the vector. How can i do this?

Comment: You have a class `VectorsPro` and a constructor for `Vector` - That's not possible.

Comment: Don't use Vector. It shouldn't be used for years and years. Use ArrayList. Don't use raw types either. Generics exist for more than 10 years now. So use ArrayList<Integer>. And use a loop. If you got the idea of using Vector from a book, then buy a newer one. If you got it from a teacher, then, well, all hope is lost.

Comment: 1. Read lines 2. Split 3. Compare string 4. Do what is requested

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to define a Vector class (and if so, why are you naming it Vectors), or are you trying to use the standard java.util.Vector class in your own class named Vectors (and, if so, what is that incorrect constructor Vector(...)?). Please post code that at least compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Vectors` class name is a typo, and it's actually `Vector`:

```
Vector v = new Vector(length);
Arrays.fill(v.elements, value);
return v;
```

Comment: Ah, right, if the OP is actually defining a Vector class and not using the standard java.util.Vector one.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I dont think so that the case. Class name is `Vectors` where as constructor name is `Vector`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below.

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int length = 5, value  = 4;
            Vector vector = new Vector(Collections.nCopies(length, value));

            System.out.println(vector);
        }
    }
```

It will output:

```
[4,4,4,4,4]
```