# Way to create a copy of an array of vectors for further modification

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating my own Vector class which is able to perform many different computations. However I seem to have come across an obstacle. I have a few methods such as sorting, scalar add/multiply and reversing methods which I need to perform, however I want to create a copy of the vector first so that I can modify it.
This is my code of just the sorting method as an example:

```
    Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++){
            if (vector.elements[i] > vector.elements[j]) {
                long temp = vector.elements[i];
                vector.elements[i] = vector.elements[j];
                vector.elements[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return vector;
```

In the above code, whenever I seem to run it, the output is always 0. However I know I need to create a clone of the vector input by the user and store it in the `Vector "vector"` object. 
How can I do this?

The instance variables I have are listed below:

```
public class Vector {

private Long sum;
private Long mode;
private Long median;
private Long minimum;
private Long maximum;

private final int length;
private final long[] elements;

public Vector(int length) {

    this.sum = null;
    this.mode = null;
    this.median = null;
    this.minimum = null;
    this.maximum = null;

    this.length = length;
    this.elements = new long[length];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a copy constructor, i.e. `Vector(Vector other)`:

- Assign all of the scalar fields using `this.sum = other.sum;` etc;
- Assign the array fields using:

  ```
  this.elements = Arrays.copyOf(other.elements, other.elements.length);
  ```

(It's not clear why you need a `length` field, since `elements.length == length` - just use `elements.length`)

Comment: ```length``` seems to be part of the template: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954961/unsure-how-to-set-uniform-value-to-a-vector/36954985)

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer!